Unable to use contact plugin to get contact data from robot
I am trying to simulate a snake robot that is navigating obstacles.
In the process, I need to know when a part or link of the robot hits an obstacle and how much force it experiences from the contact.

I am using "contact plugin" but I get

a log entry where topic name is different from the topic name I defined:
  [gzserver-1] [INFO] [1714412192.556439992] [link1_bumper_plugin]: Publishing contact states to [/bumper_states]


and no data upon quering this new topic name:
header:
   stamp:
     sec: 417
     nanosec: 723000000
   frame_id: link_2
states: []



Gazebo reference:
    <gazebo reference="link_2">
        <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
        <sensor name="link1_contact_bumper" type="contact">
            <always_on>true</always_on>
            <contact>
                <collision>link_2_collision</collision>
            </contact>
            <update_rate>1</update_rate>
            <plugin name="link1_bumper_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_bumper.so">
                <frame_name>link_2</frame_name>
                <bumperTopicName>link1_bumper</bumperTopicName>
            </plugin>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>

Please can you help get this contact sensor working so I can get contact force and other info.

Code Repository: https://github.com/dashanan13/snake-robot-sim/tree/main
Branch: 3obstacles-contactsensor

